# Cursor for loop to return output in proper format in oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, cursor

I have below procedure in which i want to return the output of variable value `brand_name.BRAND_NAME`. I am getting the correct output. But i want to return it in proper format. For example right now i am getting the output as

```
BRAND_NAMES:FNC
BRAND_NAMES:LIDL
```

But i want to return the output as:

```
BRAND_NAME: FNC,LIDL
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
FUNCTION BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY
(
  IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP
, IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC IN VARCHAR2
, IN_KPI_LOG_ID IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
V_KPI_DEF_ID NUMBER := '';
V_BRAND_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '';
V_KPI_TYPE_ID NUMBER := '';

CURSOR brand_names_cur 
IS
Select BR.NAME AS BRAND_NAME INTO V_BRAND_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION_BRAND KDB ON KD.KPI_DEF_ID = KDB.KPI_DEF_ID JOIN
RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.BRAND BR ON KDB.BRAND_ID = BR.BRAND_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

BEGIN
Select KPI_DEF_ID INTO V_KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_LOGS WHERE KPI_LOG_ID = IN_KPI_LOG_ID;

Select KT.KPI_TYPE_ID INTO V_KPI_TYPE_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

    FOR brand_name IN brand_names_cur
    LOOP
    BODY := BODY || 'BRAND_NAME:' || brand_name.BRAND_NAME || Chr(10) || Chr(13);
    END LOOP;   

BODY := BODY || 'ALERT_DESCRIPTION:' || to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC);

    RETURN BODY;
END BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY;
```

Comment: Accumulate your list without the "header' and :chr(10), chr(13), THEN at the end add "BRAND_NAME:' and CR/LF? Good luck.

Comment: i dont understood shellter ...can you please put it into answer section with example ?

Comment: sorry, I have to leave for the day. Think about it for a few minutes, you'll get it. Very easy.

Comment: if your list of brand_names is not too long, you can use listagg function to get the comma separated values, and then concatenate to `'BRAND_NAME: '`

Answer (score 0):

Add V_FIRST_RECORD variable

```
V_FIRST_RECORD Boolean := true;
```

and use it in your loop like this

```
if v_first_record then
  body := 'BRAND_NAME: '||brane_name.BRAND_NAME;
else
  body := body ||','||brane_name.BRAND_NAME;
  v_first_record := false;
end if;
```

Comment: i am getting the result as ,FNC,LIDL with no header

Comment: You have to initialize your boolean variable as true, i think